# node red / JS : calculate time elapsed

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have no experience with JS, but I need to get the time from a node red flow where the payload return the date in this format : `2022-09-03 08:23:39.806170+00:00` and then compare to the sensor.time which is the current date to return the elapsed time.

so something like this VarElapsed to (MyPayload - sensor.time)
again I have no experience with JS so I would thing this would be the result but thatss probably doesn't make any sense...

```
var d=new Date();
var start_time=payload

d=new Date();
var end_time=d.getTime()
var difference =end_time-start_time;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is cool to instantiate a new Date object.

```js
var payload = "2022-09-03 08:23:39.806170+00:00";

var start_time = (new Date(payload)).getTime();
var d = new Date();
var end_time = d.getTime()
var difference = end_time - start_time;
console.log("difference in ms: ", difference)
```